# Watch on controller scope from directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on an AngularJs application and I have a confusing issue here when I am trying to watch on controller scope property within link function of a directive

Here is minimal example of the issue

**HTML**

```
<div  fc-loading="filterBox"></div>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.filterBox = false;
   setInterval(function () { 
    $scope.filterBox = !$scope.filterBox;
},2000)
}
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fcLoading', function () {
return{
    scope:{
        fcLoading:'='
    },
    link: function (scope,ele,attrs) {
        scope.$watch(scope[attrs.fcLoading],function(newValue, oldValue){

            console.log(newValue)
        }
     }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify: what variable are you trying to watch. Are you trying to watch the fcLoading variable, or are you trying to watch a variable with the name of whatever string is in attrs.fcLoading?

Comment: attrs.fcLoading is equivalent to filterBox which is the name of the property in the scope of controller `$scope.filterBox` I am using the attributes to just isolate the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJs Directive scope **'='** method lets you to have **2 ways binding** inside your directive, and you can only watch your **directives scope variable**.like this

```
scope.$watch('fcLoading', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue);
}, true)
```

By the way call $scope.$apply() inside setInterval function or use $interval

Comment: Thanks a lot but this will always  returns a `undefined`

Comment: undefined ? why? If your directive is inside controller, then every change $watch function will catch

Comment: because the name of the property I want to watch on is `$scope.filterBox` not `$scope.fcLoading` please have a look on my controller

Comment: nooo.I'm just saying that.2 ways binding lets you to use $scope.fcLoading

Comment: I know this but I don't know why it always returns `undefined `

Comment: oooh.Found the problem

Comment: If you use setInterval you have to call $scope.$apply() or you can use $interval (as angular style and not needed $apply() function)

Comment: Thanks!!!! you save my day when you said `If you use setInterval you have to call $scope.$apply() ` everything was correct on my code but the way I updating the value for testing was incorrect is worked now! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just watch the value that you're putting on the scope here:

```
scope:{
    fcLoading:'='
},
```

like this in your link function:

```
scope.$watch(scope.fcLoading, function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your answer has a syntax error as fcLoading is not defined it should be 'fcLoading' and it didn't work after fixing this unfortunately

Comment: scope.fcLoading is a value of something which in my case equal to false,watch should work on a name of property not on a value